# Calculate $m(a) = \mathbb{E}[X-(X-a)_+]$ for $X\sim \text{Ber}(p)$ with $p\in(0,1)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

How does one calculate such a thing? I know the definition of the expectation, which would lead me to
$$
m(a) = \mathbb{E}[X-(X-a)_+] = p - \mathbb{E}[(X-a)_+] = \begin{cases} p - (1-p)a - p(1+a) = - 2a,& -a > 0, \\ 
p - p(1+a) = -a,&-a\leq 0 ~\wedge~1-a>0\\
p, & 1-a\leq 0, \end{cases}
$$
but I don't know if I calculated the second expectation correctly, I think I did not.

Comment: Why do you speak of "estimates"? There are no estimation involved here. You mean expectation?

Comment: wops, yes, I mean expectations

Comment: It might be easier to first note $$X - (X-a)_+ = \min(X,a)$$ and then split into cases depending on $a$.  For each of $a < 0$ and $a> 1$, then minimum is easy to find.  For $0 \leq a \leq 1$, we can write it as $aX$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $$X - (X - a)_+ = \begin{cases} X, & X \le a \\
a, & X > a. \end{cases}$$  Since $X \in \{0,1\}$, this leads to the following  cases:

Case 1:  $a < 0$.  Then $\Pr[X \le a] = 0$ and we always have $X - (X-a)_+ = a$.

Case 2:  $a = 0$.  Then $X-(X-a)_+ = 0$.

Case 3:  $0 < a < 1$.  Then $\Pr[X \le a] = \Pr[X = 0] = 1-p$, hence $\Pr[X - (X - a)_+ = 0] = 1-p$, otherwise $\Pr[X - (X-a)_+ = a] = p$.  That is to say, $$\frac{X - (X-a)_+}{a} \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p).$$

Case 4:  $a \ge 1$.  Then $X - (X - a)_+ = X$.

For these cases, we have

$$\operatorname{E}[X - (X-a)_+] = \begin{cases}
a, & a \le 0 \\
ap, & 0 < a < 1 \\
p, & a \ge 1.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you! One can do the same for the variance, am I right?

Comment: I would get
\begin{align*}
        v(a) &= \text{Var}[X-(x-a)_+] = \begin{cases} 0,&a\leq 0,\\ a^2p(1-p), & 0<a<1, \\ p(1-p),& a\geq 1. \end{cases}\end{align*}
Is this correct?

Comment: @question Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help!